# Change TextView to name of location

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to change the text of my TextView to the name of the location the marker indicates. The problem I'm having is that I have to call this name from another java-file, and this doesn't seem to work.

In the PlaceInfo.java -file:
The PlaceInfo file gets the name of the location of the marker (the location you search for). This is done with the Google Maps API.

```
public class PlaceInfo {

private String address;
private LatLng latLng;
private String name;

public PlaceInfo(String name, String address, LatLng latLng) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.latLng = latLng;
}


public PlaceInfo() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public LatLng getLatLng() {
    return latLng;
}

public void setLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
    this.latLng = latLng;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PlaceInfo{" +
            "address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", latLng=" + latLng +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';



}
```

}

And in the Activity with the textview. The one that should be changed since the problem is here.

```
public class MarkerActivity extends Activity {

    private PlaceInfo mPlace;
    private TextView textElement;
    private Context context;



    ImageView imageView;

    Random r;

    Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.markerphoto1,
            R.drawable.markerphoto2,
            R.drawable.markerphoto3,
            R.drawable.markerphoto4
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker);
        context = this;





        //random image on page
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        r = new Random();
        imageView.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);

        //set font for location_title
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(location_title);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        //set location_title to name of location

        mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
        textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_title);
        textElement.setText(String.valueOf(mPlace.getName()));


    }

}
```

Now the code for the callback, located in the MapActivity.

```
    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
            places.release();
            return;
        }
        final Place place = places.get(0);
        mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
        mPlace.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
        mPlace.setLatLng(place.getLatLng());
        mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());

        moveCamera(mPlace.getLatLng(), DEFAULT_ZOOM);


    }
};
```

I hope you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: are you getting the value ? and if yes then share this in your question. so that i can help you out.

Comment: You are using two different textViews here - `title` and `textElement`. And what is `PlaceInfo.class`? You should use an object, not the class itself - `PlaceInfo p = new PlaceInfo()...`

Comment: @TDG I changed the question. Maybe it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String address; 
private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
            mPlace.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
            mPlace.setLatLng(place.getLatLng());
            mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());

            address = place.getAddress().toString();

            moveCamera(mPlace.getLatLng(), DEFAULT_ZOOM);

        }
```

And in MarkerActivity

```
 textElement.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("address"));
```

Comment: "missing return statement" in the PlaceInfo-file and var name is assigned to itself?

Comment: + the PlaceInfo file provides the name of the location, found with the Google Map API. So there is no point in setting a new name.

Comment: So you can use only getName().

Comment: PlaceInfo pi = new PlaceInfo();
        textElement.setText(pi.setName()); Like this?

Comment: textElement.setText(pi.getName());

Comment: No, but right now I added every code that has to do with this problem. Please look at the question details.

Comment: You are setting name in MapActivity and retrieving it in Marker activity. It will not work like this. You have to use Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the object of `PlaceInfo` `class` to `getName`. But you are calling the `class` object.

it should be something like below

```
textElement.setText(placeInfo.getName());
```

Comment: if its static, just use PlaceInfo.getName(). do not add ".class"

Comment: yeah, I did it that way... Still doesn't work. Please read my edited question.

Comment: from where are you setting the name in PlaceInfo class?

Comment: private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
            mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());

        }
    };

Comment: In the MapActivity (google maps API), I get the current name, address, etc... So the name from the PlaceInfo.java file depends on the selected location if that makes sense

Comment: So you are not using static references. You are using an object to save the data. So you need the same object to diplay the data

Comment: try using mPlaceInfo.getName(). Am guessing you have mPlaceInfo object created at activity level. Lets see

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.simon_pc.chargeme.models.PlaceInfo.getName()' on a null object reference... Any chances I could contact you outside Stackoverflow since my reputation is under 4

Comment: please share the full class code. That will help to fix it fast

Comment: Edited the question. Now you have on one hand the PlaceInfo.jave (=MODEL) and the MarkerActivity.java (=ACTIVITY). I now don't get any errors anymore, but the text just doesn't show up.

Comment: this is not sufficient. also share the code which has mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback